# Is there a word "호젖하다" in Korean?

Tags: word-usage

I'm now using [the following Memrise course](https://www.memrise.com/course/368149/hangugeo-topik-eohwi-gogeub-50-days-advanced-topik/45/) and found the following word:

> 호젖하다
>
> quiet/lonesome (고적하다/한적하다/적적하다)

But when I search on the web, the first and second results are the aforementioned Memrise course, and there are only 5,780 matches to begin with.

The third results onward have Korean results, but it is difficult to understand them as they seem to be quite minor web pages, not the entry page of a web dictionary.

In fact, all the dictionary apps I tried did not have the entry for 호젖하다 (nor 호젖).

So my question is, is there such word in Korean? And if there is, is the definition above correct? And when do you use the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct spelling is [호젓하다](https://en.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koen/a2af709d8fe34b43b1177ccb5df9096a).

However, 호젖 is a [possible misspelling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%ED%98%B8%EC%A0%96%22), as of January 2020: around 10,000 hits on Google. Still a magnitude of order lower than the correct [호젓](https://www.google.com/search?q=%ED%98%B8%EC%A0%93), which is above 200,000.

Comment: Thanks! I also guessed it is possibly a typo...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a supplement to the [accepted answer](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/5646/91)

Searching for [호젖하다 in naver autocorrects it into 호젓하다](https://search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=top_hty&fbm=1&ie=utf8&query=%ED%98%B8%EC%A0%96%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4) and the first result is the dictionary definition

I suppose this is a common typo in Korean

In general naver.com will give better search results for text containing Hanguel, but google is probably better for a mixture of Hanguel and English